# Is there a way to use the same global variable between two shared objects?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have two shared objects a.so and b.so.

In my another file, c.cc, I have a `int x = 0;`

When x is incremented in a.so I want this to be reflected in b.so.

Is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: How does `a.so` modify `x` if it's defined in `c.cc`?

Comment: I was thinking something like using extern int x; from c.h ?
I don't know, man - that's why I am here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

**a.cc**

```
extern int x;

void incrementX() {
  x++;
}
```

**b.cc**

```
#include <iostream>

extern int x;

void printX() {
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

**c.cc**

```
void incrementX();
void printX();

int x = 0;

int main() {
  incrementX();
  printX();
  incrementX();
  printX();
  incrementX();
  printX();
}
```

Then compile, link and run:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -shared -oa.so a.cc
$ clang++ -Wall -shared -ob.so b.cc
$ clang++ -Wall -oc ./a.so ./b.so c.cc
$ ./c
1
2
3
```

You'll probably want to put the declarations (`extern int x;`, `void incrementX();`, `void printX();`) in headers rather than in the `*.cc` files, but that doesn't make a difference to the linker or at runtime.

(Note that I wrote my `main` function in `c.cc` to keep things simple, but resulting in a cyclical dependency between `c` and each of `a` and `b`. Normally you'd have a cleaner dependency graph, probably by having `a` and `b` both depend on `c`, but putting the `main` function in `d`.)